# Django Models: Multiplication of two fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to multiply two fields from the model and display it in a template. I have two models:

```
class Priority(models.Model):
    priorityName=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    priorityScore=models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.priorityScore)

class ImpactMatrix(models.Model):
    objectName=models.ForeignKey(ObjectName,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actionName=models.ForeignKey(ActionObject,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority=models.ForeignKey(Priority,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='priority')
    functional=models.ForeignKey(Priority,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='functional')
    supervision=models.ForeignKey(Priority,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='supervision')
    approval=models.ForeignKey(Priority,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='approval')
```

I want to multiply the priorityScore in ImpactMatrix.priority * ImpactMatrix.functional

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#property) in model and access it from template as any other model field,

```
class ImpactMatrix(models.Model):
    objectName = models.ForeignKey(ObjectName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actionName = models.ForeignKey(ActionObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='priority')
    functional = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='functional')
    supervision = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='supervision')
    approval = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='approval')

    @property
    def some_name(self):
        return self.priority.priorityScore*self.functional.priorityScore
```

and in your tempate,

```
{% impactmatrix_object.some_name %}
```

Comment: If some of you (like me) found that there is a little bit of black magic in the @property decorator, I found this to be a helpful tutorial on the why's and the how's of using it: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom template tag.

you can refer the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) for more info about custom template tags

```
@register.simple_tag()
def multiply(priority, functional, *args, **kwargs):
    return priority * functional
```

and you can you the tag in template like this

```
{% load your_custom_template_tags %}
{% multiply im_obj.priority.priorityScore  im_obj.functional.priorityScore %}
```